# Found nil table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I have a 2d array:

```
var s = [["Maths"],["English"]]
```

`cellPressed` is a variable to find the cell pressed in the previous view which is all working

Every time I do:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Cell: subjectTableViewCell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subjectCell") as! subjectTableViewCell
    Cell.subjectName.text = s[cellPressed][indexPath.row]
    return Cell
}
```

I get:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Have you set the correct identifier in the storyboard? + Have you attached the class subjectTableViewCell in the storyboard? (And a quick thing: try naming your variables with lowerCamelCase and classes with UpperCamelCase)

Comment: Yeh i checked it all, and will do? sorry new to this

Comment: Is this the exact code that you're using right now?

Comment: yeah i am, any help?

Comment: If i remove 'Cell.subjectName.text = s[cellPressed][indexPath.row]' the error goes away but i want the label to show the text?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a 2D array actually. Are you coming from another view where you selected Maths?

Comment: i selected a students name, that gives me the cellPressed, and the subjects in the 2d array, so if cellPressed = 0 the student studies all the values in the first array? Do you see where im coming from?

Comment: Are you overriding the numberOfRowsInSection method? If so, what does it return?

Comment: yes and it returns 1, because of one subject. If i remove Cell.subjectName.text = s[cellPressed][indexPath.row] the label apperas, so its something to do with that?

Comment: It could only be two things. 1: Your cell is nil (meaning you setup something wrong) or 2: s[cellPressed][indexPath.row] is nil. Actually, I think only the first one is possible because it would actually crash if it were out of range. I suggest reading a quick tutorial on UITableView to make sure you set it up correct. (And debug!)

Comment: OMG! I FIGURED IT OUT! tHE outlet wasnt even connected thats why i was getting nil! Thanks anyways!

Comment: James u can add the solution so i can do that tick thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could only be two things.

1. Your cell is nil (meaning you setup something wrong!)
2. s[cellPressed][indexPath.row] is nil

Actually, I think only the first one is possible because it would actually crash if it were out of range so make sure your cell is completely configured before accessing it!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following. You shouldn't force the unwrapping of the cell.

```
func tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
     let Cell: subjectTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subjectCell") as? subjectTableViewCell ?? subjectTableViewCell()
     Cell.subjectName.text = s[cellPressed][indexPath.row]
     return Cell
```

}

Comment: Also, its most likely that your subjectName is nil from the sound of it. You can do a simple check for that with the following if Cell.subjectName.text == nil {print("subject name is nil")}

Comment: thanks for your help man, but i figured it out, the outlet wasnt even connected? thought i did but it some hoe got disconnected!